# How to create an Pareto output for a sum function?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a larger database table, with one column (bigint) hosting the filesize in byte. There are ~75 million rows in this table.

Now I like to generate a Pareto-like agrregation, with filesize steps as categories.
The output shall have 4 calculated columns:

1. file size range
2. calculated:   count
3. calculated:   percentage of total count
4. calculated:   sum of filesize
5. calculated:   percentage of total filesize

Example:
row 1: <100 kB,   12345 files,  0,01%  (of all files),   6783 byte,  0.0001% of total filesize
row 2: 100kB->500kB, 45678 files,  0,03%  (of all files),  124548 byte, 0.0003% of total filesize
row 3: 500kB->  1MB, ...
row 4: ...
row n: >100GB,  24 files, 0,0001%  (of all files),  32425634232223654535 byte,  5.432% of total filesize

The grouping (in byte) could be provided in a separate SQL table when this makes sense.
So far, I have tried to query all those rows individually   (select sum(filesize) where filesize > xyz), and did the final calculations etc. in Excel.  But this seems odd.

What is the correct way to do this in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=03abb888f92034bda97d271c755ac4f8)

```
SELECT 
    CASE                                                       -- 2
        WHEN filesize < 100 THEN '< 100'
        WHEN filesize BETWEEN 100 AND 1000 THEN '100 - 1000'
        WHEN filesize > 1000 THEN '> 1000'
    END,
    COUNT(*) as cnt_files,
    COUNT(*) / (s.cnt) as percentage_files,                    -- 4
    SUM(filesize) as total_data,
    SUM(filesize) / (s.total) as percentage_data
FROM f
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT
        COUNT(*)::numeric as cnt,
        SUM(filesize)::numeric as total                        -- 1
    FROM f
) s
GROUP BY 1, s.cnt, s.total                                     -- 3
```

1. Calculate the total values (entire data size, number of all files)
2. Create groups of your data
3. `GROUP BY` your recently created groups
4. Aggregate the data per group and - if necessary - create percentages using the total values.